# How are Unikernels different from Containers?

Tags: linux, kernel, containers

Unikernels are a new thing and I am having trouble understanding what their use cases are.

Any use case I can think of is already served by the existence of Docker Containers.

So what are Unikernels meant to be used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Containers share kernel space with the other containers on a physical hypervisor. Generally, unikernels do not. All the functional differences are basically manifestations of that root difference.

Containers have a larger kernel space attack surface, for instance, because a container's kernel is general purpose: any application can run in any container of the right OS.  A unikernel is customized to only contain the subsystems needed by the running application -- only *that* application can run in the appropriate unikernel, thus the unikernel has a radically smaller attack surface.

Also, unikernels have more direct access to the underlying hardware -- thus they're more efficient than containers (also as a result of the slimmer kernel size, although that depends a lot on how many containers or unikernels run on a particular hypervisor).  Also, unikernels traditionally (this is changing) can only run *one* process, so forking isn't an option for applications running in traditional unikernels.

So, unikernels are more secure and faster; but more custom fit, thus less general purpose.  They're meant to be used for any workflow that prioritizes efficiency and security over OS repurposing and standardization.